# Text Outline not working with android X device

Tags: java, android

I am using below custom class for make text outline in my quotes application. Its working fine till device with android 9. In android 10 device, its not giving me any error as well not working.
My custom class for draw outline is like below

```
public class OutlineTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    private Field colorField;
    private int textColor;
    private int outlineColor;

    public OutlineTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public OutlineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    }

    public OutlineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        try {
            colorField = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCurTextColor");
            colorField.setAccessible(true);


            textColor = getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OutlineTextView);
            outlineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.OutlineTextView_outlineColor, Color.TRANSPARENT);
            setOutlineStrokeWidth(a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.OutlineTextView_outlineWidth, 0));
            a.recycle();
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            colorField = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextColor(int color) {
        textColor = color;
        super.setTextColor(color);
    }

    public void setOutlineColor(int color) {
        invalidate();
        outlineColor = color;

    }

    public void setOutlineWidth(float width) {
        invalidate();
        setOutlineStrokeWidth(width);

    }

    private void setOutlineStrokeWidth(float width) {
        invalidate();
        getPaint().setStrokeWidth(2 * width + 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (colorField != null) {
            // Outline
            setColorField(outlineColor);
            getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            // Reset for text
            setColorField(textColor);
            getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void setColorField(int color) {
        // We did the null check in onDraw()
        try {
            colorField.setInt(this, color);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Optionally catch Exception and remove print after testing
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I am calling it from my RecyclerView like this

```
CardMainActivity.text_quotes.setOutlineColor(Color.parseColor(CardConstant.getcolorcodearray().get(getAdapterPosition())));
```

My gradle build information is like below

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
```

Let me know if someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Your class is using reflection to look up `mCurTextColor`. Have you double checked that field still exists in Android 10? Reflection may break at any time with OS updates.

Comment: @MH.You are right, its not there in android 10, https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/non-sdk-q. There any solution? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need to use reflection at all. And to make it work with Android 10, you'll need to move away from it anyways,.. Instead of reflection, you could use `getTextColors()` 
and `setTextColor(ColorStateList)` - both public methods. And to turn your `int outlineColor` into a `ColorStateList`, use `ColorStateList.valueOf(outlineColor)`. Unless I overlooked something, those are all the ingredients you need to update your `OutlineTextView`.